# Django Recaptcha fails the form validation

Tags: django, web, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm implementing RecaptchaV3 on a Django application.
I am currently following this github(https://github.com/kbytesys/django-recaptcha3) README text to set it up.

I have a feedback form that sends an email with the subject and text.

However, when I add RecaptchaField in django form, the POST request no longer passes the form.is_valid() in views.py.

Does anyone have a thought/fix on how to overcome this problem?

Thank you in advance

forms.py

```
class contactForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name (required)'}))
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email (required)'}))
subject = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Subject'}))
message= forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Message'}))
captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    form = contactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = contactForm(request.POST)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            print("form is valid")
        
    form = contactForm()
    return render(request, 'homepage/home.html', {'form':form, 'context':context,})
```

template

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" method="POST" action="?">
           {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Your Name (required)</label><br>
                                {{ form.name }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Your Email (required)</label><br>
                                {{ form.email }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subject">Subject</label><br>
                                {{ form.subject }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message">Your Message</label><br>
                                {{ form.message }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn" type="submit">SEND</button>
                    </form>
```

in the header, i've added

```
{% recaptcha_init %}
{% recaptcha_ready action_name='Homepage' %}
```

Comment: Do you not get an error on the form when it is not valid?

Comment: No there is no error displayed. It just doesn't trigger the code inside the if statement (if form.is_valid())

Comment: There must be something in `form.non_field_errors()` or `form.errors`?

Comment: You're right. When I tried printing form.errors, it says the captcha field is required. I thought it was sent through the request with the form. Do you know how to send captcha form through POST request?

Comment: Can you add your form, view and template?

Comment: Hi, I added it into the main question

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still need to include captcha field in your form: `{{ form.captcha }}` is missing from your template?

Comment: Thank you!! I can pass the form.is_valid now!!